# Magento import price from 10 CSV to 1000 in magento

Tags: price, import, csv

When I import a CSV file and set the price to 5,95(euros)
the products import without a problem except for one.

The price which was 5,95 or 12,95 turned into 595,00 or 1.295,00.

Does anyone have experience with this issue? Did I set some price option incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the price with the dot notation, so 5.95 instead of 5,95!